# Node 6.2/Mocha 2.4.5: syntax errors on string template and default parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Running mocha tests in node I'm getting the following syntax errors.

[String Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): this one worked on 4.4, but is failing on 6.2.

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/admin.js:18
        ROOT: `${homeDir}/.config`,
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

full code:

```
var homeDir = os.homedir(),
configLocations = {
    ROOT: `${homeDir}/.config`,
    BASE: `${homeDir}/.config/nobjs`,
    FILE: `${homeDir}/.config/nobjs/nobjs_config.json`
};
```

[Default Parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters):

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/nobutil.js:4
function splitStringToArray(str, seperator = ','){
                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

These fail when I try to run mocha tests.

[These seem to be supported.](http://node.green/#default-function-parameters)

All simple contrived examples seem to be working in the console.  Is mocha the problem?

Comment: How are you calling Mocha? What does this return: `head -1 $(which mocha)`

Comment: @robertklep result: `#!/mnt/shared/sbin/node`  I'm just calling it as straight 'mocha' or mocha [filenam.js]

Comment: That looks weird. What does `/mnt/shared/sbin/node --version` say, and where is your normal Node executable installed (`which node`)? Perhaps you should reinstall Mocha.

Comment: node -v 6.2.0, npm -v 3.8.9, mocha --version 2.4.5, btw, im using nvm on c9.io

Comment: Ah okay that would explain the strange path. However, it seems to me like it may be caused by something specific to c9.io, because I can't replicate the issue locally.

Comment: maybe my mocha is calling the wrong node?

which node
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node
robin:~/workspace (master) $ which npm
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm
robin:~/workspace (master) $ which mocha
/mnt/shared/sbin/mocha

Comment: I thought you stated that `/mnt/shared/sbin/node` is v6.2.0? That's the one that Mocha is calling, switching Node version with `nvm` won't change that because the path in the Mocha executable is hard coded. Try this, if possible: `node /mnt/shared/sbin/mocha ...`

Comment: ok, i installed mocha locally and ran it from there and it worked, i'll just put that in my path for now.  thanks.  great tip: `head -1 $(which mocha)`

Comment: Good to read you solved it. And great nick ;-)

Comment: thanks. though it worked when i called a single file, it fails when just call straight mocha, but i know what the root problem is so i can play around with it.  I'll report back what i figure out.  `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:634
        throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '" + path + "'");
        
^Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'mocha'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @robertklep 's tip, it is a path problem, global mocha running the tests using system installed node on cloud9.

by installing mocha locally and prefixing my path so that mocha is resolved first, mocha calls my default nvm installed node.

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mocha/bin:$PATH
```